# Removed XBLA games

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-live-arcade

What games are no longer available in XBLA?

Why have they been removed, and are they still available in some regions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Games can be removed from XBLA if they meet Microsofts criteria, which basically says if the game is not doing well, it can be removed. Once delisted, I don't think they're available in any region anymore.

> Microsoft announced that games older
>   than 6 months would become eligible
>   for delisting from the service if they
>   had a Metacritic score below 65 and a
>   conversion rate  below 6%. The
>   objective was to "focus the catalogue
>   more on larger, more immersive games
>   and make it much easier to find the
>   games you are looking for."

Games that have been removed include

- 5th Grader
- [Battlestar Galactica](http://web.archive.org/web/20090614013827/http://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/b/battlestargalacticaxboxlivearcade/)
- Catan
- Cyberball 2072
- [Dash of Destruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash_of_Destruction)
- Defender
- Double Dragon
- [Dream Chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Chronicles)
- Gauntlet
- Joust
- [Lost Cities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Cities_%28video_game%29)
- [Marble Blast Ultra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marble_Blast_Ultra)
- [Outrun Online Arcade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OutRun_Online_Arcade)
- Paperboy
- [Robotron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotron:_2084)
- Rootbeer Tapper
- Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3
- Sega Rally Online Arcade
- Smash TV
- Speedball 2: Brutal Deluxe
- EA Sports Fantasy Football Live Draft Tracker
- EA Sports Fantasy Football Live Score Tracker
- Yaris

Comment: Are there any sites that keep track of this information before the games are removed from XBLA, to give you one last chance to buy 'em before they disappear forever?

Comment: @Christian, not that I know of. It seems to be a case by case basis as to whether the games are silently removed or there is an announcement ahead of time.

Comment: Usually websites like trueachievements.com do a good job mentioning things like this in their news feeds, but I don't know a website just dedicated to this.

Comment: I had heard tale, of Microsoft having a method for which users could re-download purchased games that had since been removed. But that it entails hounding them until they send you a special code that you would enter, that would then trigger the download.

Comment: @Bob You can usually re-download anything straight from your download history.