# Is there any way to access delisted Xbox Live Arcade games?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-live-arcade

I am a big fan of Joust and Paperboy and found out there were Xbox Live Arcade versions of these games.

However, I found out that the games have been delisted from the Xbox Marketplace. I was wondering if there was a way to play/purchase delisted Xbox Live Arcade games if they haven't been bought yet so a player can still get achievements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removed XBLA games](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3410/removed-xbla-games)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delisted Xbox Live Arcade games can only be accessed if they've already been purchased under your account. In that case, they can be re-downloaded by going back through your Purchase History.

Outside of that, if you haven't purchased a game yet and it's been delisted, there's no way to get it.

Comment: A shame that this is true. Although there are still plenty of games available, and the ones that have been de-listed you probably already have, or never wanted anyway, right?

Comment: Has this been confirmed? Can you really re-download a delisted game if you've deleted it from your hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can get some games via download code, some exist but are rare, like joust or tmnt arcade. check ebay or bestbuy.com